# What is "Grassicher"? or what could it have been a muddling of?

Tags: etymology, single-word-request, german-to-english, technical-terminology

In William Tarrant's 1862 *Ningpo to Shanghai*, he displays a highly Victorian aversion to calling rape (the plant) by its actual name. Instead of just using Latin, though, [he opts for the bizarre coinage "Grassicher"](https://archive.org/details/cu31924023226446/page/n15/mode/2up).

As far as Wiktionary knows, that word [doesn't exist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grassicher) or is a misformed compound of ['grass'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gras#German) and ['safe'](http://en.wiktionary/org/wiki/sicher#German). Similarly, Google just seems to bring up a lot of discussions of the Polizei seizing marijuana in drug busts. Google Books mostly seems to break the two component words across sentences.

Does anyone know what Germanic word Tarrant was *trying* to say when he called rapeseed "Grassicher"?

Comment: It rhymes a little with *Brassica* (the botanical genus of rape) - maybe he tried to say that but misheard it somehow? Interesting question!

Comment: As you say yourself, it's not a German word. Just a mistake, not a mystery.

Comment: Eh, maybe, but that isn't what I said. What I said is that my Googling didn't find anything that seems relevant. Then again it's possible it's a variant spelling or dialectical name or just something he cribbed some some German botanist whose phrasing never hit the mainstream. It _seems_ much too distinct from Brassica to only be a garbling of that.

Comment: Perhaps you should also ask on "Earth Science.SE" with tag "agriculture".

Comment: @PaulFrost It's obviously a very minor usage. If there's a certain answer, it would involve pretty esoteric linguistic knowledge; since it's obviously not Latin and you guys are authoritatively downplaying any possible German connection, the only remaining place would be the English SE. I'm a bit loathe to bother though, since I doubt they'll be able to add anything to what you guys have put together here and it would just get shut down as opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suspect that Tarrant was not basing his word coinage on any German or Germanic term and did not intend any reference to the German word *sicher*. In fact, I would assume he intended the word to rhyme with *richer*, not with *sicker* – or, if he intended a long /i/ sound as in *why*, corresponding words; I cannot find a correspondence to *richer* off the top of my head but take *hiker* for *sicker*. (*Wisher* might be closer to the German pronunciation of *sicher* but not all English speakers know this finer point of German phonology.)

All of Tarrant’s known biography places him in British Hong Kong or adjacent China. While there was a German colony (‘concession’) in Hankou (present-day Wuhan), most other German possessions in East Asia were closer to Beijing and thus far away from the central or southern Chinese area that Tarrant is known to have been in. Unfortunately, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tarrant) doesn’t have information on his  early life before he arrived in Hong Kong in 1837 – it also doesn’t even give an approximate birth date.

For the record, the passage of the book can be found on [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ningpo_to_Shanghai_in_1857/Kong-keao_to_Ning-kong-jow), where also the [footnote](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ningpo_to_Shanghai_in_1857/Notes#n1) can be accessed. Tarrant directly references Robert Fortune’s [*Wanderings*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/54720/54720-h/54720-h.htm) (*Three Years’ Wanderings in the Northern Provinces of China*). It is clear that the plant he has been referring to is termed *Brassica chinensis* by Fortune and Tarrant himself described it as a variant of *B. napus* (rapeseed). So obviously, using *rapeseed* or *B. napus* wouldn’t have been accurate to Tarrant because he considers it a different plant thus precluding the use of the common name.

One other potential option is that this was a misspelling introduced by some scribe or copy-editor. Maybe Tarrant dictated *Brassica* but for some unknown reason it was misheard and thus written down as *grassica/grassicher* at that exact one spot in the book. On the other hand, Tarrant may have jumbled around a couple of letters of *brassica* – a term he was clearly familiar with.

Unfortunately though, barring the discoveries of additional diary notes or the likes of Tarrant or a medium contacting his soul in the realm of the dead we have no way of finding out for sure.

Comment: Another pointer: The source mentions "Grassicher Beans" and Brassica seeds are also called beans in some sources.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it is German word (or belongs to another Germanic language). If one reads "Grassicher", one could think that it is a compound of the German words "Gras" and "sicher", but that does not make much sense. However, if an English reader believes it is German, he would perhaps pronounce it like "Grassica".

In your source we can read

[image: Ningpo to Shanghai page 2]

There is an other occurrence on p. 8:

[image: Ningbo to Shanghai page 8]

This shows that "Beans Grassicher" or "Grassicher Beans" is the
name of some plant. As you write in your question, Tarrant wants to avoid calling rape by its actual name. I therefore believe, as pointed out in comments and Jan's answer, that Tarrant misspelled the Latin word "[Brassica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica)". Whether he really wanted to describe "Brassica napus" (rape) or "[Brassica rapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_rapa)" or something else in this family, remains open. Howewer, in combination with "beans" it is most likely that he meant rape.

[image]

PS. A Google search for "Grassica" yields hits like [this](https://pixabay.com/de/images/search/grassica%20rapa/.) and [that](https://pixabay.com/de/images/search/grassica%20rapa/). This shows that the same misunderstanding still occurs. Moreover, searching for "Krassica" which sounds similar yields a few results like [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=w_5NAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=krassica&source=bl&ots=eTqPXmh9AZ&sig=ACfU3U0EwALRJqhMnuasTShZJB4b8q5Jcg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqjpn2-c7pAhWGiqQKHYO5BV0Q6AEwCHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=krassica&f=false). The (German) text contains "Brassica", obviously the OCR software did not identify it correctly.

**Edited:**

rastafile points out in a comment that Tarrant's book contains footnotes, in particular footnote (1) which gives an explanation of "Grassicher":

[image]

Tarrant refers to [Robert Fortune's](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Fortune) book "Three years wanderings in the northern provinces of China", see [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=xukI1GCbEYsC&pg=PA346&lpg=PA346&dq=robert+fortune+brassica&source=bl&ots=NPFRDGIiZU&sig=ACfU3U2UszIkLRVZEYqtUz8G6WnYqjGvuA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL9cboltDpAhWNmIsKHaguCgcQ6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=robert%20fortune%20brassica&f=false). It seems that my theory that "Grassicher Beans" is a compound expression for a single plant is false. Probably it is just a missing comma between the two words. In Fortune's book one finds various listings of plants clearly showing this:

[image]

The cabbage oil plant is *Brassica chinensis*. It would be interesting to clarify whether the [German translation](https://www.amazon.de/Dreij%C3%A4hrige-Wanderungen-Nord-Provinzen-China/dp/B007BG50K6) of Fortune's book is the source of the strange word "Grassicher".

**Edited:**

The German translatiuon can be found [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN51254302X?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[2],%22panX%22:0.729,%22panY%22:0.465,%22view%22:%22export%22,%22zoom%22:0.686%7D). It does not contain the word "Grassicher". See p. 46.

[image]

Comment: This remains a big mystery. Did you follow the **(1)  footnote**? There is a whole page of "notes" on Brassica napus and chinensis at the end.  So why not "Brassica beans"? My guess is it was first acoustically misspelled to "Brassicher" (by the secretary) and then visually to "Grassicher" (by the printer). It was even his gazette...

Comment: @rastafile No, I didn't, thank you for your comment. I shall edit my answer to include this infoemation.